# OnPress the whole screen just disappears .Why is this happening?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
const onPress = (id) =>
{
   setState(data.map((item)=> item.id === id?      !item.isSelected:item.isSelected)

)}


.........


<TouchableOpacity  style={styles.card}
        onPress={()=>
        onPress(item)}>
```

When I press on the component it just vanishes from the screen. Why does this happen?

Comment: We'd probably need to see more code.  Is `state` (as set by `setState`) supposed to be an array of Booleans? That's what `onPress` will make.

Comment: No its an array of objects.

Comment: OK, then the `setState` call you have is not what you want. I'm guessing you want to set `isSelected` fields to `true` or `false` according to whether `item.id === id`?

Comment: Don't link to files unless you do so [in addition to having all the relevant code in your post](/help/how-to-ask). It is strongly recommended to run through the [mcve] exercise (because that almost always lets _you_ find the problem without even needing SO), and then use the resulting code from that exercise if you're still stuck at the end.

Comment: Ok  @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Comment: Don't just comment with OK, also actually edit your post or it's just going to get closed for lacking the necessary details =)

Answer (score 0):

Your current `onPress` code is replacing each item with a single Boolean value, either `!item.isSelected` or `item.isSelected`. Presumably you just wanted to update the `isSelected` field, and leave other fields intact. Here is code that does so:

```js
const onPress = (id) => {
   setState(state.map((item) => (
     {...item,
      isSelected:
        item.id === id
        ? !item.isSelected
        : item.isSelected
     })));
)}
```

(I'm not sure what `data` is in your code above, but I'm guessing you meant `state`.)

Comment: data was the array of objects

Comment: Sorry, the object needed to be wrapped in parentheses. I updated my answer.